# como obtener el nombre del mes en php

Tags: php

lo que sucede es que requiero obtener el nombre del mes y el año de la siguiente forma: nov.2018 , en vb.net logro hacerlo con esta liea de codigo `"MonthName(MENUPRINCIPAL.DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.Month, True)`pero tambien lo requiero en php "alguna idea se los agradecería mucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con que lo hagas de este modo

```
<?php

echo date("M.Y");
```

Para que el valor te sea devuelto en forma de palabra ocupas la `M` mayúscula y la Y para el año

usas el método `date` para que los valores antes mencionados sean interpretados como año y mes

Como bien me hacen la observación, te añado un ejemplo para una fecha que tu pases como valor dinámico

```
<?php

$fecha = "2018-11-25";

echo date("M.Y", strtotime($fecha));
```

Comment: shadow creo que se refiere a una fecha seleccionada, añade la opcion para una fecha dada a la respuesta `date("M.Y", strtotime($fecha)`

Comment: @JDev gracias por la observación